# How to stop below mentioned jQuery fading and sliding after 15 seconds? Right now it is going infinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery

This banner has animation which takes 3 seconds to animate. I want to
   stop this 3 seconds cycle after 5 cycles. Can you please help me with
   the same? I tried for loop and if statement but unable to achieve my goal

```
function showBanner(){    
  $(".banner").fadeIn("slow", function(){  
    $("h1").slideDown("slow", function(){   
      $("h2").slideDown("slow", function(){ 
        $(".logo").fadeIn("slow", function(){  
          setTimeout(hideBanner, 3000);  
        }); 
      });   
    });
  });
}

function hideBanner(){
  $(".logo").fadeOut("slow", function(){
    $("h2").slideUp("slow", function(){
      $("h1").slideUp("slow", function(){
        $(".banner").fadeOut("fast", function(){
          showBanner();
        });
      });
    });
  });
}

showBanner();
```

Answer (score 0):

The outer function could be used:

```
function banner(loops){    
    function showBanner(){    
        $(".banner").fadeIn("slow", function(){  
            $("h1").slideDown("slow", function(){   
                $("h2").slideDown("slow", function(){ 
                    $(".logo").fadeIn("slow", function(){  
                        setTimeout(hideBanner, 3000);  
                    }); 
                });   
            });
        });
    }

    function hideBanner(){
        $(".logo").fadeOut("slow", function(){
            $("h2").slideUp("slow", function(){
                $("h1").slideUp("slow", function(){
                    $(".banner").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                        --loops && showBanner();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
}

banner(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

first their is some basic reasons 

1- Use the JQuery file and then check that you link to a latest version of its js file.

2- follow some sample code for best ideas like Orbit Time code and word press add ons.

3- read this sample

```
jQuery(document).foundation({
  orbit: {animation: '<?php echo $Animation; ?>', // Sets the type of animation used for transitioning between slides, can also be 'fade'
      timer_speed: 15, // Sets the amount of time in milliseconds before transitioning a slide
      pause_on_hover: <?php echo $pauseOnHover; ?>, // Pauses on the current slide while hovering
      resume_on_mouseout: <?php echo $pauseOnHover; ?>, // If pause on hover is set to true, this setting resumes playback after mousing out of slide
```

***// $pauseOnHover is a bool property returns a true or false. depends on a loop in its property. so in that loop you can make a condition like cycling times and timer period.***

first link to

```
$doc->addStyleSheet( $modURL . '/css/orbit.css');
if ($params->get('jQuery')) {$doc->addScript ('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js');}
$doc->addScript($modURL . '/js/foundation.min.js');
```

**best wishes to you.**